# How to parse xml files containing symbols like '&, <>,~' using python

Tags: python, xml

I get `TypeError: Type 'NoneType' cannot be serialized.`while reading the following xml file

```
<root>
 <sub_component> 
     Hii & heloo <> 
 </sub_component>
</root>
```

The code I use for coding is as follows

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True) # recover from bad characters.
root = etree.fromstring(file_path, parser=parser)
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Comment: That is not valid XML

Comment: unfortunately I have a file like this and it need to be processed.. Any means for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup= BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'html.parser')
```